# Convert Map Object from String "[a:12,b:[a:b,c:d]]"

Tags: java, groovy

Is there any out of box method in java (groovy) that converts the string like

```
String s = "[a:12,b:[a:b,c:d]]";
```

to a Map object with key value pairs.

Update: It is somehow similar to the question asked as **Groovy: isn't there a stringToMap out of the box?**([Groovy: isn't there a stringToMap out of the box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212606/groovy-isnt-there-a-stringtomap-out-of-the-box)). The difference is here the keys are of string type which makes easier to parse, since i have retrieved the mentioned map by doing `.toString()` i am unable to parse by the answered methods because my string actually contains date strings which i need it back to date objects. So it was difficult to parse the whole string.

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct way, but someone has asked more or less the same question before here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212606/groovy-isnt-there-a-stringtomap-out-of-the-box

Comment: who hands you down sucha "map"?  i bet it's a toString somewhere, and you are way better off preventing that _or_ use some form of serialization, that is actually sane

Comment: Yes i did toString() to a map, since i need it to pass it to a controller as a whole and convert it as a map object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this string to JSON-like format, and simple parse it:

```
String s = "[a:12,b:[a:b,c:d]]";
def result = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(s.replaceAll('\\[', '{').replaceAll('\\]', '}'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what i am searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way that may work depending on your actual data.  The problem with your sample data is that you supply unquoted strings b and d as part of the structure:

```
String s = "[a:12,b:[a:b,c:d]]";
```

If what you had was actually

```
String s = "[a:12,b:[a:'b',c:'d']]";
```

or

```
String s = "[a:12,b:[a:1,c:2]]";
```

Then you could just do this:

```
def map=Eval.me(s)
```

but as is, eval tries to resolve b and d as variables which aren't defined in the scope.